# крах системы при обращении к adb linux

Tags: android, linux, adb

Всем привет. При попытке запуска сервера adb система виснет намертво. Погомает только выключение кнопкой. Замена стандартного порта 5037 на другой дала рабочий adb на один раз, теперь этот фокус не работает. Система linuxmint kde 18. 64bit. Более того, подобная проблема возникает и на других дистрибутивах. Использовался ADB как установленый через репозитории дистрибутива, так и скачаный вместе с sdk. Одинаковый результат дает обращение к adb и через терминал и через AndroidStudio. Тестировал в том числе и с разными ядрами от 3.10 до 4.7. Куда копать?)

Comment: Попробуйте тут посмотреть: http://stackoverflow.com/q/29172905/3212712

Comment: Такое же сообщение от strace. Советуют поставить 32бит версию. будет ли потеря производительности в таком случае?

Comment: Я ни разу не сталкивался с такой проблемой и ни разу не юзал линукс. По поводу потери производительности тоже ничего сказать не могу. Я лишь привёл ссылку, кою нашёл в гугле)

Comment: В коде `adb` нет ничего такого *особого*, что могло бы привести к зависанию. Смотреть в сторону кривых драйверов USB контроллера. Удалите из системы (выключите в настройках биоса) все USB контроллеры производителей отличных от Intel/NEC/Renesas.